# Cannot copy files between mapped drives when using @file variable

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

**Desired behaviour:**
I wish to copy `.log` files from one network location to another. This does work when one drive is local and another is network, however network to network location and I get a error when using `@files` variable.

**Specific problem:**
The following below will list all files in a given directory and then copy them to another network location. I always get the same error: `Invalid argument/option - '@file'`. This does however work when I copy from local drive to network location, but not network location to network location, even if I map the drives:

```
forfiles /M *.log /P "\\10.11.233.91\vol_tx01\AsRunLogs\Playbox25" /c "cmd /c COPY @file "\\172.16.2.118\Live_Engineering\AsRuns\PBOX01""
    #ERROR: Cannot use UNC
```

Or mapped folders:

```
forfiles /M *.log /P ":Z\" /c "cmd /c COPY @file ":/Y""
    #ERROR: INVALID argument/option - '@file'
```

Comment: You need to escape literal `"` after `/c` of `forfiles` like `\"`, so try this: `forfiles /M *.log /P "Z:\\" /c "cmd /c COPY @file \"Y:\\\""`; alternatively replace every `"` with `0x22`: `forfiles /M *.log /P "Z:\\" /c "cmd /c COPY @file 0x22Y:0x5C0x22"`... (I assume by `:Z\` and `:Y/` you mean `Z:\` and `Y:\`, resp.)

Comment: Thank you. But now output is "cannot find the file specified"

Comment: I see no reason to use `FORFILES` at all.  A simple `Copy` or  `FOR` command will do just fine to iterate through the files you want to copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with (this does ini files)

```
copy \\127.0.0.1\C$\windows\*.ini \\127.0.0.1\D$\*.*
```

You are using no features of `forfiles` that copy doesn't have.